# How to print an additional * after every 5th and following 3rd number in a positive integer sequence?

Tags: java

I'm trying to print

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, *, 6, 7, 8, *, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, *, 14, 15, 16, *, 17, ...
```

where an additional `*` should be printed after every 5th and following 3rd integer repeatedly.

Here's my current code

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

which prints

```
1, 2, 3, 4, *, 6, 7, 8, 9, *, 11, 12, 13, 14, *, 16, 17, ...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey! Could you explain what logic the expected output follows to be as it is?

Comment: It shows ('*') every first 5 number, and next 3 numbers. But the numbers is increment normally

Comment: This is pretty much figuring out the formula. You have 5, 8, 13, 16, 21, etc. So it follows that these indices lie after a gap of 5, or 5+3 (8), or 5+(8n). So from there, you could check `if ((i-5) % 8 == 0 || i % 8 == 0)`, and if so, print an asterisk in your pattern _after_ printing your number. After all, the numbers are always printed

Comment: (should also clarify, it's "5+(8n)" or it's "8n", hence the `||` in the resulting conditional)

Comment: @Frusciante110 If your question is solved, make sure to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is giving the expected output:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        if ((i-5) % 8 == 0 || i % 8 == 0) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
    }
  }
}

// Output: 
// 1 2 3 4 5 * 6 7 8 * 9 10 11 12 13 * 14 15 16 * 17 18 19 20 21 * 22
// 23 24 * 25 26 27 28 29 * 30 31 32 * 33 34 35 36 37 * 38 39 40 * 41
// 42 43 44 45 * 46 47 48 * 49 50 51 52 53 * 54 55 56 * 57 58 59 60 61
// * 62 63 64 * 65 66 67 68 69 * 70 71 72 * 73 74 75 76 77 * 78 79 80
// * 81 82 83 84 85 * 86 87 88 * 89 90 91 92 93 * 94 95 96 * 97 98 99 100
```

Dry run link: https://repl.it/repls/MarriedPreemptiveLeadership

Also, thanks to @Rogue for coming up with the mathematical formula.

Here's the explanation provided by @Rogue

> You have 5, 8, 13, 16, 21, etc. So it follows that these indices lie
> after a gap of 5, or 5+3 (8), or 5+(8n). So from there, you could
> check if ((i-5) % 8 == 0 || i % 8 == 0), and if so, print an asterisk
> in your pattern after printing your number. After all, the numbers are
> always printed.

Comment: And what exactly have *you* done?

Comment: @akuzminykh updated answer with quoting Rogue's explanation mentioned in the question comment section.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say how to make it show what you want, but the reason it's showing `*` at every 5 (5, 10, 15, etc.) is that `%` is a "modulus" operator which gets the remainder after dividing.

So `5 % 5` does `== 0` (and thus prints out `"* "`) as there is no remainder after dividing `5 / 5`. Same as `10 / 5`, etc. `6 % 5` would give `1` as the remainder.

Comment: OP has clarified the logic behind the expected output. You should edit your answer to provide the solution.